# Send and receive bytes in ApiController

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I trying to send front my client and receive in my controller the following object :

```
public class FileParameter
{
    public byte[]? File { get; set; }
    public string? FileName { get; set; }
    public string? ContentType { get; set; }

    public FileParameter() 
    {
    }
}
```

My controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult GetFileOIT([FromForm]FileParameter fileParameter)
{
    try
    {
        string x = fileParameter.FileName;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest(ex.Message);
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

In my client :

```
foreach (FileParameter item in files)
{
    MultipartFormDataContent multiForm = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    multiForm.Add(new StringContent(item.FileName), "FileName");

    var bytes = new ByteArrayContent(item.File);
    bytes.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    multiForm.Add(bytes, "File");
    multiForm.Add(new StringContent(item.ContentType), "ContentType");

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:5074/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = client.PostAsync("api/Calculator/GetFileOIT", multiForm).Result;

    if (httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        // string ss = httpResponseMessage.StatusCode.ToString();
        var  response = httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }
    else
    {
        var content = httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        // .msg = content;
        // string str = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); ;
    }

    // File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\demo\\"+item.FileName, item.File);
}
```

I also try to change in my controller to `[FromForm]`, `[FromBody]`, in my client changing from `octet-string` to `www-form` but I'm no able to receive anything in my controller or "415 unsupported Content-Type".

Thanks in advance

Comment: You probably want `multiForm.Add(bytes, "fileParameter");` to match your function. Also do not use `.Result` as that can cause a deadlock, instead use `await`

Comment: Hello did you try the solution provided? Does it resolve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Change your client code like below:

```
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;

[HttpPost]
public void Create([FromForm]List<FileParameter> files)
{
    foreach (FileParameter item in files)
    {
        StringContent content1 = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(item), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:5074/");
        HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = client.PostAsync("api/Calculator/GetFileOIT", content1).Result;
        if (httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            //string ss = httpResponseMessage.StatusCode.ToString();
            var response = httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        }
        else
        {
            var content = httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            //.msg = content;
            //string str = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); ;
        }
        //File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\demo\\"+item.FileName, item.File);
    }
}
```

For your controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("/api/Calculator/GetFileOIT")]
public IActionResult GetFileOIT([FromBody] FileParameter fileParameter)
{

    try
    {
        string x = fileParameter.FileName;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest(ex.Message);
    }

    return Ok(fileParameter);
}
```